# Time series Multiple breakpoints test in R

Tags: r, regression, time-series, structural-change

I'm using package strucchange in R to deal with time series data, but I have a question about breakpoints() function, how to set the optimal period 'h' to the regression sample? if the period h too short, it's become very sensitive, every small shock will be conclude in the change points.

Here is my code, first, i'm generate and combine two ar(1) with trend data to one [image]

```
xt <- ts(arima.sim(n=100, list(order=c(1,0,0), ar = c(.9))))

xtt <- 100 + xt -0.5 * seq(100)

xt <- ts(arima.sim(n=100, list(order=c(1,0,0), ar = c(.9))))

xtt1 <- 80 + xt -0.5 * seq(100)

vec <- c(xtt,xtt1)

l <- length(vec)

plot(vec,type = "l")

tt <- 1:(l-1)

tt1 <- 1:l

brk <- breakpoints(ts(vec[2:200]) ~ vec[1:199] + tt, h = 40)
```

Using AR(1)+Constant+Trend to OLS

```
summary(brk)
```

With the RSS & BIC Suggestion, Which is the best choice guidelines? With the plot, i choice breakpoints = 2

[image]

```
brk <- breakpoints(ts(vec[2:200]) ~ vec[1:199] + tt, h = 20)
```

Then I reduce the period from 40 to 20

```
summary(brk)
```

i choice breakpoints = 2

[image]

Then, if I choice smaller period of regression samole h = 10, it's become very sensitive. Almost 17 breakpoints.

```
brk <- breakpoints(ts(vec[2:200]) ~ vec[1:199] + tt, h = 10)
```

[image]

How to choice the optimal period h ? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a model with breakpoints fits the data well, then the choice of `h` should not matter too much, as long as it is large enough to fit the model reliably on every subset. With a model like this (linear trend + strong autocorrelation), you will at least 25 observations per subset, maybe more.

This is also what I get when I `set.seed(1)` before running your code. I always get 2 breakpoints, the first at observation 99, the second as close to 99 as my `h` allows. The second break is to account for the autocorrelation coefficient following the shift.

BIC-based selection of the number of breakpoints, however, was found to be not so reliable by Bai & Perron (2003, *Journal of Applied Econometrics*). In this particular case, it appears to be reasonable though.

Lastly, I wonder why you don't model this in first differences. Then you only have a single pulse at observation 99 and otherwise a stable model.

Comment: Hello professor , thanks for your helpful reply, It's my pleasure to get your answer. I didn't use the first difference because of my research focus on trend to forecast , so i need to choice recent value to foerecast , like using after the points of structure change values, but my datas is short about  30 to 40. Is small sample suitable for verification multiple breaks test?

Comment: Re: trend. The question is whether your time series is really stable around a deterministic trend. You could test for trend stationarity (after removing breaks) to check whether possibly an integrated model would fit better. Note that the intercept of the first differences corresponds to the slope of the trend. Re: Sample size. If your changes are really as large as in the artificial example, then 30-40 observation might work ok. _[And if the reply helped you resolve the problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark on the left of the answer below the vote count.]_

Comment: I think i got it, thanks for very helpful advices!